# Swift - SDWebImage / Duplicate definition of category "WebCache"

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

When I have imported the `SDWebImage` framework into my project.

I get 2 warning messages.

They all say `'Duplicate definition of category "WebCache" on interface "UIImageView" '`

Besides, there is one also shown `'In module "WebImage" import from <built-in>:1: '`

How to hide or make sure it won't show out anymore?

**Note:**

The Framework imported, and linked with binary files. And I'am using swift so that I linked the bridge as well -> `"#import 《SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h》 "`

Answer (score 8):

Use `@import SDWebImage;` instead of `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` (not just in the bridge file but anywhere in your project).